# Maximizing the minimum machine completion time

Tags: scheduling, approximation-algorithms

There are $n$ jobs with different processing times, and they should be scheduled on $m$ identical machines such that the *smallest* completion time is as *large* as possible. This problem is NP-hard even for $m=2$, by reduction from partition. I am looking for an FPTAS for it.

I found an FPTAS for a very similar problem: making the *largest* completion time (the "makespan") as *small* as possible. It is in this paper:

> Sartaj K. Sahni (1976). [Algorithms for Scheduling Independent Tasks](https://doi.org/10.1145/321921.321934). Journal of the ACM. 23 (1): 116–127.

There is an algorithm that finds a schedule with makespan at most $1+\epsilon$ of the minimum in time $O(n\cdot (n^2 / \epsilon)^{m-1})$. This is an FPTAS for any fixed $m$.

For the original problem, which is to make the *smallest* finish time as *large* as possible, I only found a PTAS:

> Gerhard Woeginger (1997). [A polynomial-time approximation scheme for maximizing the minimum machine completion time](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167637796000557). Operations Research Letters. 20 (4): 149-154.

But the author considers it "impractical". Is there an FPTAS for this problem?

Alternatively, since the 1976 paper is quite hard for me to understand: is there a simpler FPTAS for minimizing the makespan, or a paper that explains the above FPTAS in a simpler way?